# xsd .net soap response field placed in extension Any instead of defined class

Tags: .net, xsd, wsdl

I have a soap response

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <ns1:Correlation xmlns:ns1="http://customer.com/contract/vho/header/v1">
      <ns1:ConversationID>0db85463-df83-465d-bd15-5eec0b3ce2ec</ns1:ConversationID>
   </ns1:Correlation>
    <ns1:Source xmlns:ns1="http://customer.com/contract/vho/header/v1">
      <ns1:System>CC</ns1:System>
   </ns1:Source>
    <wsa:Action xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://customer.com/contract/vbs/payment/process-card-payment/v1/establish</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://customer.com/contract/vbs/payment/process-card-payment/v1/establish</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:RelatesTo xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">8ae6b3d6-b748-43d6-aa1a-6204a934c6de</wsa:RelatesTo>
    <wsa:To xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:To>
    <tns:ResultStatus xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:vfo="http://customer.com/contract/vfo/fault/v1" xmlns:cmn="http://customer.com/schema/common/v1" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:ns2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/bf-2" xmlns:ns1="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:standard:CoreComponentType:2" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://customer.com/contract/vho/header/v1">
      <vfo:Name>1006</vfo:Name>
      <vfo:Message>Invalid ChargeAccountNumber (not found).</vfo:Message>
   </tns:ResultStatus>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soap-env:Body xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The Name and Message are place in the Any extension of the ResultStatus object when seen/used from the consuming .Net code. The SOAP service is added as a service reference to the .net project, the relevant source XSD used is as follows:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:cmn="http://customer.com/schema/common/v1" xmlns:tns="http://customer.com/contract/vho/header/v1" xmlns:vfo="http://customer.com/contract/vfo/fault/v1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://customer.com/contract/vho/header/v1" version="1.1" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="./Fault.xsd" namespace="http://customer.com/contract/vfo/fault/v1" />
  <xsd:element name="Source" type="tns:SourceType" />
  <xsd:element name="Destination" type="tns:DestinationType" />
  <xsd:element name="Correlation" type="tns:CorrelationType" />
  <xsd:element name="Cache" type="tns:CacheType" />
  <xsd:element name="ServiceDocumentation" type="tns:ServiceDocumentationType" />
  <xsd:element name="ResultStatus" type="vfo:FaultType" />
..cut for brevity
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:ws-bf="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/bf-2" xmlns:cmn="http://customer.com/schema/common/v1" xmlns:tns="http://customer.com/contract/vfo/fault/v1" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://customer.com/contract/vfo/fault/v1" version="1.1" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="./bf-2.xsd" namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/bf-2" />
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="./Meta.xsd" namespace="http://customer.com/schema/common/v1" />
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="./CodeLists.xsd" namespace="http://customer.com/schema/common/v1" />
  <xsd:element name="Fault" type="tns:FaultType">
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:complexType name="FaultType">
    <xsd:complexContent mixed="false">
      <xsd:extension base="ws-bf:BaseFaultType">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Name" type="xsd:normalizedString">
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Severity" type="cmn:FaultSeverityCodeType">
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Category" type="cmn:FaultCategoryCodeType">
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="ReasonCode" type="xsd:string">
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Message" type="xsd:string">
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Specification">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Characteristic" type="cmn:CharacteristicType">
                </xsd:element>
              </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Failures">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Failure" type="tns:FailureType">
                </xsd:element>
              </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>

  ...../bf-2.xsd
  
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:wsrf-bf="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/bf-2" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/bf-2" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="./ws-addr.xsd" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="./xml.xsd" namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>
        Get access to the xml: attribute groups for xml:lang as declared on 'schema'
        and 'documentation' below
      </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
  </xsd:import>
  <xsd:element name="BaseFault" type="wsrf-bf:BaseFaultType" />
  <xsd:complexType name="BaseFaultType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="##other" processContents="lax" />
      <xsd:element name="Timestamp" type="xsd:dateTime" />
      <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Originator" type="wsa:EndpointReferenceType" />
      <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="ErrorCode">
        <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
          <xsd:complexContent mixed="true">
            <xsd:extension base="xsd:anyType">
              <xsd:attribute name="dialect" type="xsd:anyURI" use="required" />
            </xsd:extension>
          </xsd:complexContent>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Description">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
              <xsd:attribute ref="xml:lang" use="optional" />
            </xsd:extension>
          </xsd:simpleContent>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="FaultCause">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax" />
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax" />
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

The relevant parts of generated proxy reference code in .Net is as follows :

```js
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
    public partial class AuthoriseCardPaymentResponse {
        
        [System.ServiceModel.MessageHeaderAttribute(Namespace="http://customer.com/contract/vho/header/v1")]
        public WcfFastBreak.ProcessCardPayment.SourceType Source;
        
        [System.ServiceModel.MessageHeaderAttribute(Namespace="http://customer.com/contract/vho/header/v1")]
        public WcfFastBreak.ProcessCardPayment.DestinationType Destination;
        
        [System.ServiceModel.MessageHeaderAttribute(Namespace="http://customer.com/contract/vho/header/v1")]
        public WcfFastBreak.ProcessCardPayment.CorrelationType Correlation;
        
        [System.ServiceModel.MessageHeaderAttribute(Namespace="http://customer.com/contract/vho/header/v1")]
        public WcfFastBreak.ProcessCardPayment.CacheType Cache;
        
        [System.ServiceModel.MessageHeaderAttribute(Namespace="http://customer.com/contract/vho/header/v1")]
        public WcfFastBreak.ProcessCardPayment.ServiceDocumentationType ServiceDocumentation;
        
        [System.ServiceModel.MessageHeaderAttribute(Namespace="http://customer.com/contract/vho/header/v1")]
        public WcfFastBreak.ProcessCardPayment.FaultType ResultStatus;
        
        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://customer.com/schema/vbm/payment/card-payment/v1", Order=0)]
        public WcfFastBreak.ProcessCardPayment.AuthoriseCardPaymentVBMResponseType AuthoriseCardPaymentVBMResponse;
        
        public AuthoriseCardPaymentResponse() {
        }
        
        public AuthoriseCardPaymentResponse(WcfFastBreak.ProcessCardPayment.SourceType Source, WcfFastBreak.ProcessCardPayment.DestinationType Destination, WcfFastBreak.ProcessCardPayment.CorrelationType Correlation, WcfFastBreak.ProcessCardPayment.CacheType Cache, WcfFastBreak.ProcessCardPayment.ServiceDocumentationType ServiceDocumentation, WcfFastBreak.ProcessCardPayment.FaultType ResultStatus, WcfFastBreak.ProcessCardPayment.AuthoriseCardPaymentVBMResponseType AuthoriseCardPaymentVBMResponse) {
            this.Source = Source;
            this.Destination = Destination;
            this.Correlation = Correlation;
            this.Cache = Cache;
            this.ServiceDocumentation = ServiceDocumentation;
            this.ResultStatus = ResultStatus;
            this.AuthoriseCardPaymentVBMResponse = AuthoriseCardPaymentVBMResponse;
        }
    }
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34281")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://customer.com/contract/vfo/fault/v1")]
    public partial class FaultType : BaseFaultType {
        
        private string nameField;
        
        private FaultSeverityCodeType severityField;
        
        private bool severityFieldSpecified;
        
        private FaultCategoryCodeType categoryField;
        
        private bool categoryFieldSpecified;
        
        private string reasonCodeField;
        
        private string messageField;
        
        private CharacteristicType[] specificationField;
        
        private FailureType[] failuresField;
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="normalizedString", Order=0)]
        public string Name {
            get {
                return this.nameField;
            }
            set {
                this.nameField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
        public FaultSeverityCodeType Severity {
            get {
                return this.severityField;
            }
            set {
                this.severityField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Severity");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
        public bool SeveritySpecified {
            get {
                return this.severityFieldSpecified;
            }
            set {
                this.severityFieldSpecified = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("SeveritySpecified");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=2)]
        public FaultCategoryCodeType Category {
            get {
                return this.categoryField;
            }
            set {
                this.categoryField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Category");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
        public bool CategorySpecified {
            get {
                return this.categoryFieldSpecified;
            }
            set {
                this.categoryFieldSpecified = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("CategorySpecified");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=3)]
        public string ReasonCode {
            get {
                return this.reasonCodeField;
            }
            set {
                this.reasonCodeField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("ReasonCode");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=4)]
        public string Message {
            get {
                return this.messageField;
            }
            set {
                this.messageField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Message");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Order=5)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Characteristic", IsNullable=false)]
        public CharacteristicType[] Specification {
            get {
                return this.specificationField;
            }
            set {
                this.specificationField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Specification");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Order=6)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Failure", IsNullable=false)]
        public FailureType[] Failures {
            get {
                return this.failuresField;
            }
            set {
                this.failuresField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Failures");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(FaultType))]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34281")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/bf-2")]
    public partial class BaseFaultType : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {
        
        private System.Xml.XmlElement[] anyField;
        
        private System.DateTime timestampField;
        
        private EndpointReferenceType originatorField;
        
        private BaseFaultTypeErrorCode errorCodeField;
        
        private BaseFaultTypeDescription[] descriptionField;
        
        private System.Xml.XmlElement faultCauseField;
        
        private System.Xml.XmlAttribute[] anyAttrField;
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute(Order=0)]
        public System.Xml.XmlElement[] Any {
            get {
                return this.anyField;
            }
            set {
                this.anyField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Any");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
        public System.DateTime Timestamp {
            get {
                return this.timestampField;
            }
            set {
                this.timestampField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Timestamp");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=2)]
        public EndpointReferenceType Originator {
            get {
                return this.originatorField;
            }
            set {
                this.originatorField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Originator");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=3)]
        public BaseFaultTypeErrorCode ErrorCode {
            get {
                return this.errorCodeField;
            }
            set {
                this.errorCodeField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("ErrorCode");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Description", Order=4)]
        public BaseFaultTypeDescription[] Description {
            get {
                return this.descriptionField;
            }
            set {
                this.descriptionField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Description");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=5)]
        public System.Xml.XmlElement FaultCause {
            get {
                return this.faultCauseField;
            }
            set {
                this.faultCauseField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("FaultCause");
            }
        }
        
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyAttributeAttribute()]
        public System.Xml.XmlAttribute[] AnyAttr {
            get {
                return this.anyAttrField;
            }
            set {
                this.anyAttrField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("AnyAttr");
            }
        }
        
        public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        
        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
            if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
                propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

So my question, is the XSD definition incorrect for this line in BaseFaultType?
As removing it from the xsd and updating the service reference places the fields in the 'correct' position of ResultStatus, or is .Net incorrectly interpreting a valid XSD? :

```html
          <xsd:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="##other" processContents="lax" />
```

XSD definition says for XSD any with ##other to be 
*##other - elements from any namespace that is not the namespace of the parent element can be present*

Comment: also noticed that changing ##other to ##local allows the fields to be placed in their correct locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BaseFault Type was flawed in design, and never corrected :
https://lists.oasis-open.org/archives/wsrf/200506/msg00060.html